# Why does int/float multiplication lead to different results?

Tags: c++, floating-point, multiplication

If I multiply a float and and integer like below, why does all multiplications lead to a differnt result? My expectation was a consistent result. I thought in both cases the int value gets implicitly converted to a float before multiplication. But there seems to be a difference. What is the reason for this differnt handling?

```
int multiply(float val, int multiplier)
{
    return val * multiplier;
}

int multiply2(float val, int multiplier)
{
    return float(val * multiplier);
}

float val = 1.3f;

int result0 = val * int(10); // 12
int result1 = 1.3f * int(10); // 13
int result3 = multiply(1.3f, 10); //12 
int result4 = multiply2(1.3f, 10); // 13
```

Thank you
 Thorsten

Comment: Is this the real code? I get the same results for both and I don't see why it would be different.

Comment: The second expression can be evaluated at compile time - what compiler are you using? Look at the byte code it produces.

Comment: Tried with g++ 4.7.3 on an Ubuntu: both multiplications lead to 13

Comment: The compiler is the build in from visual studio 2010. And yes, it is real code =)

Comment: @Floris: You are correct. The disassembly reveals that for result1 no multiplication is executed. Only the compile time const value is taken.

Comment: "_Insanity_: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results." :P

Comment: VS Express 2013 returns the result '13' for all four versions.

Answer (score 10):

What likely happens for you is:

Assuming IEEE or similar floats, 1.3 can not be represented, and likely is something like 1.299999 which multiplied by 10 is 12.99999 which then truncated to int is 12.

However 1.3 * 10 can be evaluated at compile time, leading most likely to an accurate representation of 13.

Depending on how your code is actually structured, what compiler is used, and which settings it is used with, it could evaluate either one to 12 or 13, depending on whether it does this at run, or compile time.

For completeness, with the following code, I could reproduce it:

```
extern int result0;
extern int result1;

float val = 1.3f;

void foo( )
{   
 result0 = val * int(10); // 12
 result1 = 1.3f * int(10); // 13
}
```

Comment: Is the compiler allowed to use a different representation for compile-time computation?

Comment: @sftrabbit my guess is that is implementation defined

Comment: @sftrabbit: I don't have a standard quote at hand, but afaik it is. This is also in the area of the reason for templates not allowing non-type float parameters.

Comment: @sftrabbit It's even allowed to use different representations
dynamically.  §5/11: "The values of the floating operands and
the results of floating expressions may be represented in
greater precision and range than that required by the type; the
types are not changed thereby".  And it's not implementation
defined, but unspecified.  (E.i. the implementation doesn't have
to document what it does, or even do the same thing twice in
a row.)  In fact, it could very easily change depending on the level of optimization.

Comment: @JamesKanze I think this is constrained by `…::is_iec559` and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. A compiler that defines the former to true and the latter to `0` should not do anything of the sort. A compiler that defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to `1` or `2` should generate programs that compute according to the respective models.

Comment: @PascalCuoq There are restrictions introduced in C++11, and a C++11 compiler is required to specify what it does using `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  Of the two compilers I have at hand, one (VC++ from VS 2012) doesn't support this yet, and the other (g++ 4.7.2) says `2` (always use `long double`).  (By default.  If I specify `-fpmath=sse -march=c3-2`, it says `0`.  Without the options, I get the effect the OP describes, with them, both values are 13.)